# MVC + EF Code First Many to Many relationship: Create view with checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor, many-to-many

I'm a newbie with MVC + EF Code First and have some doubts about many to many relationship.

I created 2 tables that has many to many relationship (userprofile and courses). 
Sounds simple but it got pretty complex for me:

**I want to see the "create" view of the "userprofile" with checkboxed for each of the "courses"existent options and being able to save it to corresponding databases.**

I've been reading and looking for examples but I didn't get to solved this (or to find any related information about this particular need (I found similar things that didn't apply)

I already saw this article but it's not about the create and not using EF 
(http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Courses>  usercourses { get; set; }
}

public class Courses
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string CourseDescripcion { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; } 
}

 public class UserProfileDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Courses> usrCourses{ get; set; }

}
```

The Create Controler:

```
        public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    } 

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(UserProfile userprofile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.UserProfiles.Add(userprofile);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }
        return View(userprofile);
    }
```

Regarding the view, I would like to have just the '@foreach' loop for generating the dropboxes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving Many to Many relationship data on MVC Create view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531769/saving-many-to-many-relationship-data-on-mvc-create-view)

Answer (score 2):

You asked pretty much the same question in another post which I've answered. I've laid out step by step how to do it so you can't go wrong :)

[Saving many to many relationship data on MVC Create View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531769/saving-many-to-many-relationship-data-on-mvc-create-view/11593957#11593957)